# Unsure what Unknown Provider: $attrsProvider <- $attrs means?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angular-ui-bootstrap, karma-jasmine

I am encountering the following error when I run my Karma Unit Tests:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $attrsProvider <- $attrs
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=%24attrsProvider%20%3C-%20%24attrs
        at /home/ubuntu/vantage/core/static/core/js/lib/angular.js:78:12
        at /home/ubuntu/vantage/core/static/core/js/lib/angular.js:3705:19
        at Object.getService [as get] (/home/ubuntu/vantage/core/static/core/js/lib/angular.js:3832:39)
        at /home/ubuntu/vantage/core/static/core/js/lib/angular.js:3710:45
        at getService (/home/ubuntu/vantage/core/static/core/js/lib/angular.js:3832:39)
        at invoke (/home/ubuntu/vantage/core/static/core/js/lib/angular.js:3859:13)
        at Object.instantiate (/home/ubuntu/vantage/core/static/core/js/lib/angular.js:3880:23)
        at /home/ubuntu/vantage/core/static/core/js/lib/angular.js:7134:28
        at null.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/vantage/ecommerce/js_tests/unit/progress/progressControllersSpec.js:12:20)
        at Object.invoke (/home/ubuntu/vantage/core/static/core/js/lib/angular.js:3869:17)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/home/ubuntu/vantage/core/static/core/js/lib/angular-mocks.js:2132:25)
        at null.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/vantage/ecommerce/js_tests/unit/progress/progressControllersSpec.js:10:20)
        at null.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/vantage/ecommerce/js_tests/unit/progress/progressControllersSpec.js:5:5)
        at /home/ubuntu/vantage/ecommerce/js_tests/unit/progress/progressControllersSpec.js:3:1
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'expectGET' of undefined
        at null.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/vantage/ecommerce/js_tests/unit/progress/progressControllersSpec.js:380:18)
Chrome 33.0.1750 (Linux): Executed 42 of 45 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.483 secs)
Chrome 33.0.1750 (Linux) Unit Test: ProgressController ProgressController should expect showDetailedSection to be false on initialization FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $attrsProvider <- $attrs
```

Anyone know what this means exactly and how to fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please show the code for the broken test

Comment: Ultimately you are using `$attrs` in your controller but are not providing it in your tests

Comment: This test was passing fine until we added ui.bootstrap as a dependency of the module, and now we get this.  There is no explicit reference to $attrs anywhere in our controller.  It appears that with the extra dependency, none of the services are being injected into the test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this ended up being pretty obscure.

The issue was that the bootstrap-ui package actually has a `ProgressController` in it.  So our controller got stomped on.  The test was trying to create an instance of our `ProgressController` but ended up with the one from bootstrap-ui.

Simply renaming our controller fixed everything.